# How to loop through the columns of a Matlab table by using the headings?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a for-loop for the Matlab code below. I have named each column with JAN90, FEB90, etc. all the way up to AUG19, which can be found in a matrix named "data". At this point I need to change the month and year manually to obtain the result I want. Is there a way to iterate over the columns by the column name? Would it be easier to name the columns Var1, Var2 etc.?

```
clear;
clc;
data = readtable('Data.xlsx','ReadVariableNames',false);
data(1,:) = [];
data.Var2 = str2double(data.Var2);
data.Var3 = str2double(data.Var3);
data.Var4 = str2double(data.Var4);
data.Var5 = str2double(data.Var5);
data.Var6 = str2double(data.Var6);
data.Var7 = str2double(data.Var7);
data.Var8 = str2double(data.Var8);
data.Var9 = str2double(data.Var9);
data.Var10 = str2double(data.Var10);
data.Var11 = str2double(data.Var11);
data.Var12 = str2double(data.Var12);
data.Var13 = str2double(data.Var13);
data(:,1) = [];
data = table2array(data);
data = array2table(data.');
data = table2cell(data)
data = cell2table(data, 'VariableNames',{'JAN90','FEB90','MAR90','APR90','MAY90','JUN90','JUL90','AUG90'...
    ,'SEP90','OCT90','NOV90','DEC90','JAN91','FEB91','MAR91','APR91','MAY91','JUN91','JUL91','AUG91'...
    ,'SEP91','OCT91','NOV91','DEC91','JAN92','FEB92','MAR92','APR92','MAY92','JUN92','JUL92','AUG92'...
    ,'SEP92','OCT92','NOV92','DEC92','JAN93','FEB93','MAR93','APR93','MAY93','JUN93','JUL93','AUG93'...
    ,'SEP93','OCT93','NOV93','DEC93','JAN94','FEB94','MAR94','APR94','MAY94','JUN94','JUL94','AUG94'...
    ,'SEP94','OCT94','NOV94','DEC94','JAN95','FEB95','MAR95','APR95','MAY95','JUN95','JUL95','AUG95'...
    ,'SEP95','OCT95','NOV95','DEC95','JAN96','FEB96','MAR96','APR96','MAY96','JUN96','JUL96','AUG96'...
    ,'SEP96','OCT96','NOV96','DEC96','JAN97','FEB97','MAR97','APR97','MAY97','JUN97','JUL97','AUG97'...
    ,'SEP97','OCT97','NOV97','DEC97','JAN98','FEB98','MAR98','APR98','MAY98','JUN98','JUL98','AUG98'...
    ,'SEP98','OCT98','NOV98','DEC98','JAN99','FEB99','MAR99','APR99','MAY99','JUN99','JUL99','AUG99'...
    ,'SEP99','OCT99','NOV99','DEC99','JAN00','FEB00','MAR00','APR00','MAY00','JUN00','JUL00','AUG00'...
    ,'SEP00','OCT00','NOV00','DEC00','JAN01','FEB01','MAR01','APR01','MAY01','JUN01','JUL01','AUG01'...
    ,'SEP01','OCT01','NOV01','DEC01','JAN02','FEB02','MAR02','APR02','MAY02','JUN02','JUL02','AUG02'...
    ,'SEP02','OCT02','NOV02','DEC02','JAN03','FEB03','MAR03','APR03','MAY03','JUN03','JUL03','AUG03'...
    ,'SEP03','OCT03','NOV03','DEC03','JAN04','FEB04','MAR04','APR04','MAY04','JUN04','JUL04','AUG04'...
    ,'SEP04','OCT04','NOV04','DEC04','JAN05','FEB05','MAR05','APR05','MAY05','JUN05','JUL05','AUG05'...
    ,'SEP05','OCT05','NOV05','DEC05','JAN06','FEB06','MAR06','APR06','MAY06','JUN06','JUL06','AUG06'...
    ,'SEP06','OCT06','NOV06','DEC06','JAN07','FEB07','MAR07','APR07','MAY07','JUN07','JUL07','AUG07'...
    ,'SEP07','OCT07','NOV07','DEC07','JAN08','FEB08','MAR08','APR08','MAY08','JUN08','JUL08','AUG08'...
    ,'SEP08','OCT08','NOV08','DEC08','JAN09','FEB09','MAR09','APR09','MAY09','JUN09','JUL09','AUG09'...
    ,'SEP09','OCT09','NOV09','DEC09','JAN10','FEB10','MAR10','APR10','MAY10','JUN10','JUL10','AUG10'...
    ,'SEP10','OCT10','NOV10','DEC10','JAN11','FEB11','MAR11','APR11','MAY11','JUN11','JUL11','AUG11'...
    ,'SEP11','OCT11','NOV11','DEC11','JAN12','FEB12','MAR12','APR12','MAY12','JUN12','JUL12','AUG12'...
    ,'SEP12','OCT12','NOV12','DEC12','JAN13','FEB13','MAR13','APR13','MAY13','JUN13','JUL13','AUG13'...
    ,'SEP13','OCT13','NOV13','DEC13','JAN14','FEB14','MAR14','APR14','MAY14','JUN14','JUL14','AUG14'...
    ,'SEP14','OCT14','NOV14','DEC14','JAN15','FEB15','MAR15','APR15','MAY15','JUN15','JUL15','AUG15'...
    ,'SEP15','OCT15','NOV15','DEC15','JAN16','FEB16','MAR16','APR16','MAY16','JUN16','JUL16','AUG16'...
    ,'SEP16','OCT16','NOV16','DEC16','JAN17','FEB17','MAR17','APR17','MAY17','JUN17','JUL17','AUG17'...
    ,'SEP17','OCT17','NOV17','DEC17','JAN18','FEB18','MAR18','APR18','MAY18','JUN18','JUL18','AUG18'...
    ,'SEP18','OCT18','NOV18','DEC18','JAN19','FEB19','MAR19','APR19','MAY19','JUN19','JUL19','AUG19'});
m = [1 2 3 6 12 24 36 60 84 120 240 360]';
for i=1:100
t = i;

data.X_1 = (1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t);
data.X_2 = ((1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t))-exp(-m./t);
model_1 = fitlm(data, 'FEB95 ~ X_1 + X_2');
RSS(100,:) = zeros ;
res = model_1.Residuals.Raw;
res(any(isnan(res), 2), :) = [];
RSS(i) = sum(res.^2);
end 
RSS(:,2) = [1:1:100];
min = min(RSS(:,1));
t = find(RSS(:,1) == min)
data.X_1 = (1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t);
data.X_2 = ((1-exp(-m./t))./(m./t))-exp(-m./t);
model_1 = fitlm(data, 'FEB95 ~ X_1 + X_2')
res = model_1.Residuals.Raw;
res(any(isnan(res), 2), :) = [];
RSS = sum(res.^2)
intercept = model_1.Coefficients.Estimate(1,1);
beta_1 = model_1.Coefficients.Estimate(2,1);
beta_2 = model_1.Coefficients.Estimate(3,1);
Yhat = intercept + beta_1.*data.X_1 + beta_2.*data.X_2;
plot(m, Yhat)
hold on
scatter(m, data.FEB95)
```

I.e "FEB95" should be dynamic? Any suggestions?

Comment: to get an answer, I think you need to simplify your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, can you describe the contents of the Excel file `Data.xlsx`. Your code removes the first row. Is the first row a header row? If so, why are you not reading in those column/variable names from that file?

Answer (score 0):

Her is how I would approach your problem. First realize that `VarNames=data.Properties.VariableNames` will get a list of all column names in the table. You could then loop over this list. For example

```
for v=VarNames
     current_column = v{1};
     % ....
     % Define the model spec for the current column
     model_spec = [current_column ' ~ X_1 + X_2'];
     % and create the model
     model_1 = fitlm(data, model_spec);
     % ... Continue computation ... and collect results in a table or array
end
```